# Change Dark Theme colors in NG-Zorro (Ant design for angular)

Tags: angular, tailwind-css, ant-design-pro, ng-zorro-antd

[Navbar to be changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5IFL.jpg)
I have been trying to change the color of this navbar using Tailwind (I use it instead of CSS). I did research and found that editing the `theme.less` allows changes to the theme. However it did not work, I am quite new to web development so if anyone can help it would be much appreciated.

I tried changing the `theme.less` files but it only resulted in changing the color of the hover.[[The changed color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gR6cT.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b78ns.png)

Answer (score 0):

So, I don't know much about it but you could try something onthe line of :

```
    <nav
  class="relative flex w-full flex-wrap items-center justify-between bg-neutral-900 py-3 text-neutral-200 shadow-lg lg:flex-wrap lg:justify-start"
  data-te-navbar-ref>
  <div class="flex w-full flex-wrap items-center justify-between px-6">
```

This is what I found on this website : https://tailwind-elements.com/docs/standard/navigation/navbar/

Quoting "**Navbar dark**
You can change the color of the navbar to dark by using the .bg-neutral-900 class."

Hope to be of any help

Answer (score 0):

So I did a little more research and found out that any component taken from NG-Zorro can be modified there are preset variable names mentioned on their [GitHub](https://github.com/NG-ZORRO/ng-zorro-antd/blob/master/components/style/themes/default.less). The specific values for the dark menu items are mentioned below just edit them in the `themes.less` file.

```html
@menu-dark-color: @text-color-secondary-dark;
@menu-dark-danger-color: @error-color;
@menu-dark-bg: @layout-header-background;
@menu-dark-arrow-color: #fff;
@menu-dark-inline-submenu-bg: #000c17;
@menu-dark-highlight-color: #fff;
@menu-dark-item-active-bg: @primary-color;
@menu-dark-item-active-danger-bg: @error-color;
@menu-dark-selected-item-icon-color: @white;
@menu-dark-selected-item-text-color: @white;
@menu-dark-item-hover-bg: transparent;
```